# Comments: another perspective

Tags: discussion

**Comments, *conceptual* usage *(how comments should be used)***

These are some quotes to related questions on the matter:

> Comments are temporal; they may disappear at a moment's notice without any notification to anyone. That's just their nature.
>
> Comments are not posts. They are second class citizens.
>
> There are no notifications because important information doesn't belong in comments in the first place

This is how comments should be used. However, they are not.

**Comment *real* usage *(how comments are actually used)***

Since private messaging is not supported (something I think it's completely coherent in Stack Overflow and I agree with), we are forced to use comments for *everything*.

Let's be realistic. Often, comments are the answers of a question. Sometimes, when an answer is a bit old and thus, improvable, but still valid for some people, a lot of people contribute on the comments.

Also, when an answer is dependant on something (OS, compiler version etc.), usually you can find help in the comments below, usually, highly upvoted.

**Conclusion**

If Stack Overflow had the *(1)* tools it needs to notify when a(n) answer/question/comment is edited/deleted, *(2)* a sub-answer concept to contribute to an existing answer and *(3)* a system to notify users on what flags the post has so that he can take action...

... I would agree with the *conceptual* usage. However, we are forced to use comments for all I said above, so treating them like *second class citizens* doesn't make sense to me. This said, I ask you the following:

*(TL;DR)*

**Just like a dictionary is modified to how people write/speak, why can't Stack Overflow adapt to users comment usage?**

Or at least, why not make the comment concept clear to all users ? All social networks use *comments* to give freedom to users. The *comment* name itself does not sound like something you should be able to get rid off that easily.

*Why don't they have the credit they deserve?*

Comment: *"All social networks use comments to give freedom to users"* - **this is not a social network**

Comment: "All social networks" - [so] is **not a social network**!

Comment: Yep, that's all. If the predicate is flawed, why critique the conclusions?

Comment: @UDKOX It's the second sign of a bad question, following closely behind the word "forum"

Comment: [so] is not a dictionary either ... why do you want to treat it like one?

Comment: I do understand the topic, I just disagree. I'm currently imagining all of it is not there, it's working fine; if you want people to read it differently, **edit it**.

Comment: To clarify: you are trying to explain why **you think** the comment concept is inappropriate. It's an important distinction.

Comment: Keep working on your explanation then. I don't see anything in your question to convince me that any changes are needed. Comments are not broken. Some users don't use them correctly. That doesn't mean we should change the system to accommodate them.

Comment: Those new users can read all about it at http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment, which is linked when they get the privilege. Seems clear to me. And *I'm not the one proposing a change*.

Comment: How new users unfamiliar with the platform react is an incredibly poor metric.

Comment: Are you trying to request a new feature? Possibly more than one? Or are you actually asking the question "Why..."? The "Why" is easy: because SO is meant to be a collection of high-quality questions and answers. Comments are meant for clarification of those questions and answers, which should be updated to reflect the clarifications, after which point the comments are no longer needed. If you are requesting that we change how comments should work, this should have the [tag:feature-request] tag, and outline how the change would help SO in its core mission.

Comment: What exactly is being requested here, can you clarify? Is it changing the fact that comments are sometimes subject to deletion?

Comment: You're welcome to edit it. You're not welcome to add meta-meta-content and incite others to close your question. If you didn't want to discuss this, why post?

Comment: @UDKOX I suppose sometimes comments are used to notify when an edit is made, but certainly not always (I'd argue not even the majority of times). I don't understand the relevancy of your other part of the comment. BTW, downvotes on meta generally indicate disagreement, so your edit was off-base.

Comment: Why do you want this question closed so badly? Closing the question won't prevent new comments. Only locking it or deleting it will, and there's currently not really a reason to lock it. I don't see the purpose of deleting it either, since it _is_ a discussion that could be asked in the future, meaning that this post could be used for reference in said future post. As far as I can tell, there's not really much reason to close your question, either. It's an on-topic meta question, people just disagree with your premise.

Comment: Well, if your main issue is you just don't want notified of comments on this post, the only ways to fix that are 1) Get the post locked, which I already mentioned, 2) get the post deleted, which I already mentioned, or 3) get the post disassociated from your account. Basically, you'll no longer be linked as the other of this question, meaning you won't get notifications about it and it won't be on your account. You have to contact the SE team to request this option, which could take some time. They also might not do it if they don't feel you have a good enough reason for it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Often, comments are the answers of a question.

This is *100% not the right way to use comments.* Yes, they're used that way. I myself do so when 1) I feel my "answer" does not actually answer the question, 2) I feel my answer is not complete enough to be an answer, or 3) if I know the question is a duplicate and want to quickly explain the issue while I find the duplicate. If someone points out they feel my comment *does* adequately answer the question, I will delete the comment and instead post an answer. (As an example, this answer started out as my writing a comment that I felt didn't really answer the question. As it grew, that idea changed and now I have an answer.)

If you see answers posted as comments to questions that should stay open, nudge the commentor to post an answer *or* post your own answer with the information from the comments.

> Sometimes, when an answer is a bit old and thus, improvable, but still valid for some people, a lot of people contribute on the comments.

This is *exactly what comments are supposed to be for!* Comments are for requesting clarification or *suggesting improvements* on a post. If those suggestions are truly important, they *should* be edited into the answer. If the improvement is significant and the answerer doesn't edit the information in, it could very well warrant a new answer from the commentor.

> Also, when an answer is dependant on something (OS, compiler version etc.), usually you can find help in the comments below, usually, highly upvoted.

This could be a perfectly acceptable use of comments, if they are (as with the last scenario) suggesting an improvement to the answer. If they are simply pointing out the answer is different for another OS, compiler version, etc., then that should *instead* be posted as a different answer.

> If Stack Overflow had the (1) tools it needs to notify when a(n) answer/question/comment is edited/deleted, (2) a sub-answer concept to contribute to an existing answer and (3) a system to notify users on what flags the post has so that he can take action...

Personally, I feel like Stack Overflow is fine in terms of (1). (2) is satisfied *just fine* with comments and edits. Once again, comments are for *suggesting improvements* so I see nothing else needed here.

As for (3), you shouldn't *need* to see flags on most posts to take action. If you're the OP, you should be responding to comments on the issues with your post. If you're the flagger/voter, you should flag, vote, or comment as you feel necessary, regardless of how other people see the content of the post. The only exception I could see is with questions and close flags, as seeing what your question is being close flagged/voted for can give you a bit of insight as to how to fix your question if comments aren't already being made.

> Just like a dictionary is modified to how people write/speak, why can't Stack Overflow adapt to users comment usage?

Because we aren't a dictionary. That users misuse a feature of the site is not justification for changing how the feature should be used. In reality, we should be trying to educate users on how to correctly use the feature *or* fix the feature to be harder to misuse.

> I would agree with the conceptual usage. However, we are forced to use comments for all I said above, so treating them like second class citizens doesn't make sense to me.

They're second class citizens because they *should not* contain important information for long. Two of the scenarios you pointed out they're being used for are *correct in the first place.* If you see a comment being used for another reason, for instance as a "thanks" or "great answer" comment, then flag as appropriate. If you see an answer in the comments, either suggest the commentor posts an answer or post your own.

> All social networks use comments to give freedom to users.

1) Stack Exchange and Stack Overflow are *not* social networks. Comparing us to such is comparing birds and rocks, as far as I'm concerned.

2) If I recall correctly, comments weren't even originally part of the Stack Overflow model. They were added to fill the need of requesting clarification and suggesting improvements. They were never added to give freedom to users. If users want the "freedom" comments on other sites normally give, they can try chat instead. (Preferably with the realization that chat is *still* part of the network and has rules as well, so it's not a free-for-all to talk about anything and everything however anyone wishes.)

#### Conclusion

While comments are certainly *sometimes* being misused, I don't see enough reason myself to consider changing what they are *supposed* to be used for. On top of that, there are ways to clean up bag/misused comments.

As a counter example to your points here, allow me to leave you with this: Users without enough rep to comment like to post comments as answers. Should we change the purpose of answers so they may be used as both comments and answers?

Comment: This was going to be a comment?

Comment: It originally wasn't going to be so in-depth. I was going to just hit a few broad points... When that alone turned out to be worth three comments, I decided to expand that all into an answer instead.