# Rephrase items on the Tour page

Tags: feature-request, new-users, tour-page

I think there are a few mistakes (or at least places for improvement) on the [Tour page](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). For example:

> This site is all about **getting answers**. It's not a discussion forum. There's no chit-chat.

Hmm... "There's no chit-chat." That's bull. There's plenty of chit-chat. What about all of our [memes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta)? How 'bout questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8318911/why-does-html-think-chucknorris-is-a-color)? Here's a random comment with 434 votes:

> @usr HTML is built around intentionally ignoring malformed input ;)

There's plenty of stuff like this, everywhere. It makes the site fun, and brings laughter to bored, lonely programmers. So I think that line is completely untrue. SO is about getting help to your questions, which doesn't mean just through answers. There's plenty of constructive discussion that goes on in the comments, and even more in chat. So... could we just remove that?

Also this:

> Your reputation score goes up when others **vote up** your questions, answers and edits.

Okay, well, nobody votes on edits. They approve them. Could this be changed to something like...

> Your reputation score goes up when others **vote up** your posts, and approve your edits.

But "reputation score" seems redundant and confusing. Personally, I think this would look better:

> You get reputation points when others **vote up** your posts, and approve your edits.

There's only one more thing I've got a problem with:

> *Questions that need improvement may be **closed** until someone fixes them.*

Could we add a link to a help page about closed questions? New users won't know exactly what this is, and may be confused the first time one of their questions is closed. Or something like that.

So - should we redesign the tour page, or not? Would these improvements be helpful and constructive, or are they unnecessary? Thanks for any input.

Comment: The chit-chat is not strictly meant to be about comments. We do tend to edit out all kind of noise from question and answers. But yeah, OK, chit-chat.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/268583/217863

Comment: I recalled I saw the wording of the reputation  before and I found it: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/337819/correct-imprecise-wording-about-gaining-reputation-on-the-tour-page

Comment: "Rephrase" the Tour page

Comment: Internally, voting up *is* what's done when an edit is approved. [Behold all the `UpMod`s (`2`s), and `DownMod`s (`3`s)](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/598045).

Comment: @Nathan not to be pedantic, but if the system called it a somersault...

Comment: @TinyGiant: I mean, those are actually the same values used for regular up- and down-votes.

Comment: @Nathan Well then, there you go I guess. It still doesn't make any more sense from a user's standpoint.

Comment: Related: [Is the site tour actually particularly helpful in helping people formulate good questions and answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347969/is-the-site-tour-actually-particularly-helpful-in-helping-people-formulate-good)

Answer (score 12):

> There's plenty of chit-chat...There's plenty of constructive
>   discussion that goes on in the comments.

Constructive discussion != chit-chat. When the tour says there's no "chit-chat", they mean stuff like "How's your mom doing?" It needs to be there because [too many people think Stack Overflow is a social media site](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323714/2751851) and it's not. This isn't a site for completely random discussions, not even in chat.

> You get reputation points when others vote up your posts, and approve
>   your edits.

I do agree that's clearer. I think the existing text to the right clarifies that edits are improved, though.

> Could we add a link to a help page about closed questions?

Makes sense to me.

Comment: That link you included; it's been removed. Could someone with 10k reps take a screenshot and post a link?

Comment: @Redesign [This one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323714/2751851) is just as good.

Comment: @Redesign on questions tagged [tag:feature-request], it's generally good form to not accept any answers except a) a good argument against it, or b) an answer from the SE staff confirming whether it will be implemented.

Answer (score 3):

My two cents on the phrasing changes:

> > This site is all about **getting answers**. It's not a discussion forum. There's no chit-chat.
>
> Hmm... "There's no chit-chat." That's bull. There's plenty of chit-chat. What about all of our memes? How 'bout questions like this? [...]

It is better to teach new users the rules rather than the uncodifiable exceptions.

> > Your reputation score goes up when others **vote up** your questions, answers and edits.
>
> Okay, well, nobody votes on edits. They approve them. Could this be changed to something like...

That is slightly imprecise, but I'm not sure if it is worth complicating the phrasing only so that the jargon is perfectly accurate.

> > Your reputation score goes up when others **vote up** your posts, and approve your edits.
>
> But "reputation score" seems redundant and confusing. Personally, I think this would look better:
>
> > You get reputation points when others **vote up** your posts, and approve your edits.

Well spotted. I think your formulation is an improvement, though "Your reputation increases when..." might be even better (credit to Tiny Giant for this suggestion).

Comment: *"Your reputation increases when..."*

Comment: @TinyGiant Suggestion adopted (this makes it entirely clear that reputation here is a quantity).

Answer (score 2):

> > This site is all about getting answers. It's not a discussion forum. There's no chit-chat.
>
> Hmm... "There's no chit-chat." That's bull. There's plenty of chit-chat.

Even if you're right and there *is* chit-chat, there *shouldn't* be. In other words, the site's Tour page states our *goals*. Although we may not be perfectly achieving them, they are still what we strive for, and thus the message that we want to send to new users.

Sometimes you goof off at work, too, but I'm assuming you don't put it on your resume and don't want it to define you as an employee.

> What about all of our [memes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta)?

These are memes of the *Meta* site, not memes of Stack Overflow. Big difference. Meta is significantly more relaxed, for various reasons. The "chit-chat" and "bull" and "memes" have their place (within limits) on Meta, but *not* on the main site. This, you could argue, is the major raison d'être of Meta—to give a place for this kind of stuff that keeps it off of Stack Overflow proper.

> How 'bout questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8318911/why-does-html-think-chucknorris-is-a-color)?

That might be kind of fun and interesting, but it is a serious question. [Here is an alternative phrasing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12939234/why-do-weird-things-in-font-color-attribute-produce-real-colors?noredirect=1) that may be a bit more to your liking. Fundamentally, they are the same question, though, with the same answer, which is why the other one is closed as a duplicate of the first one. The one you linked got popular because it has an interesting sounding title. These things happen.

But if you read the answers to [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8318911/why-does-html-think-chucknorris-is-a-color), you'll see that they're all serious answers. No discussion or chit-chat is going on there.

In fact, what you can't see is that there a bunch of joke answers that people have attempted to post on that question. They have been deleted because, in fact, what it says on the Tour page is the guideline that we try our hardest to stick to.

If you want to have a bit of fun when composing a question title, or when presenting your question, then that's totally fine. But there needs to be a serious and obvious programming question there, and joke answers won't be tolerated.

> Here's a random comment with 434 votes:
>
> > @usr HTML is built around intentionally ignoring malformed input ;)
>
> There's plenty of stuff like this, everywhere. It makes the site fun, and brings laughter to bored, lonely programmers. So I think that line is completely untrue. SO is about getting help to your questions, which doesn't mean just through answers. There's plenty of constructive discussion that goes on in the comments, and even more in chat. So... could we just remove that?

You appear to be mixing together the various aspects of the web site. Stack Overflow's primary mission, and the one laid out in the Tour, is a question-and-answer (Q&A) site. As such, the primary features are *questions* and *answers*. Note that *comments* and *chat* are not part of it.

You can leave humorous comments, and sometimes they're even appreciated. Other times, they're deleted. Comments are like an escape hatch, bringing a tiny bit of freeform discussion to the otherwise rigid structure of Q&A. Note that new users cannot leave comments, so they are not discussed in the Tour, since it's geared toward new users. And everyone, including experienced users, are driven toward the answer box.

Chat is something entirely different. If you want to go nuts and off-topic and engage in chit-chat, then you can do it in chat. Obviously the rules are much more relaxed there. I honestly don't think anyone coming to this web site is so new to the Internet that they don't know how a chat room works. Chat is also an *optional* feature of this web site, and does not contribute to our primary goal of getting questions answered.

So, no. We can't remove our fundamental mission statement just because the site also offers alternative means of interaction. If you're looking for laughter, there are plenty of other places on the Internet that offer that. What makes Stack Overflow unique is that we keep the laughter to a minimum and the useful programming answers to a maximum.

> Also this:
>
> > Your reputation score goes up when others **vote up** your questions, answers and edits.
>
> Okay, well, nobody votes on edits. They approve them. Could this be
> changed to something like...
>
> > Your reputation score goes up when others **vote up** your posts, and approve your edits.
>
> But "reputation score" seems redundant and confusing. Personally, I
> think this would look better:
>
> > You get reputation points when others **vote up** your posts, and approve your edits.

No real quibbles here. The Tour was designed to be simple, so I assume they didn't really want to go into a bunch of details about how exactly reputation works. This is all documented in greater detail elsewhere for the people who really want to find out. Also, the Tour evolved over time. Originally, there was no way to earn reputation from suggesting edits.

Your proposed rephrasing sounds reasonable to me. Other people have already discussed the phrasing. I'll stay out of the [bikeshedding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_triviality). I don't think the Tour as it stands now is seriously misleading people.

In fact, it wouldn't be difficult to persuade me to entirely omit the fact that suggesting edits can accrue reputation. We don't really want people suggesting edits with reputation gain as their primary motive. The motive should be *"this is unclear or badly presented, and I can fix it"*. We want editors to feel like they are making the Internet a better place, regardless of whether or not they earn reputation for doing so.

> There's only one more thing I've got a problem with:
>
> > *Questions that need improvement may be **closed** until someone fixes them.*
>
> Could we add a link to a help page about closed questions? New users
> won't know exactly what this is, and may be confused the first time
> one of their questions is closed. Or something like that.

Sure, we could do this. Adding a link is simple and relatively non-intrusive.

But it's not really a problem, because you don't *need* to understand exactly how question closure works when you're reading the Tour. I suppose this gets thrown in there just so that you are aware of it. But you don't actually need to understand how it works until one of your questions gets closed. And then, you'll be provided with copious information on closure as part of that process. Better, you'll be provided with *specific* information regarding the problem(s) with your question, based on the closure reason that was selected. Deferring the details until such time as we can provide more relevant information and the information is more relevant for the user seems like the best option.

> So - should we redesign the tour page, or not? Would these improvements be helpful and constructive, or are they unnecessary? Thanks for any input.

*Redesign* it? You haven't proposed a redesign. You've just posted some suggestions of how to improve the wording. Some of those are reasonable; others of those misconstrue the entire purpose of the web site. But no, I don't think we should redesign the Tour page—at least not based on the arguments that have been presented here. But we can certainly tweak the wording of it a bit, if you think it's worth doing so.

Personally, I think it's a better use of our time to figure out [how to improve the Ask a Question page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326868/lets-improve-stack-overflows-ask-a-question-page). This is where *most* users go wrong, and where we have the *best* chance to steer them in the right direction. Supposedly, the team is working on this, but so far all progress has been internal-only, so I have no idea where they're at on it. If you have suggestions on how to improve that, do be sure to share them, either by posting an answer to my linked question, or by posting a new question.

Feedback is always appreciated, and please don't feel like this answer is sending the message, *"No, newbie. You don't know what's going on. Shut up and stop trying to help."* We always appreciate the help and constructive feedback, and yours has certainly been constructively presented, so thank you for that.

Answer (score 2):

Related: [Is the site tour actually particularly helpful in helping people formulate good questions and answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347969/is-the-site-tour-actually-particularly-helpful-in-helping-people-formulate-good?noredirect=1&lq=1)

I completely agree with you about needing to rephrase some of the tour. I particularly dislike the paragraph that

> This site is all about getting answers. It's not a discussion forum. There's no chit-chat.

but for a different reason than you: quite simply, the tour page never actually explains what constitutes "chit-chat." Are "me too!" comments posted as answers chit-chat, for example? Are requests for clarification posted as answers "chit-chat"? Nor does the tour page explain exactly *how* Stack Overflow differs from a discussion forum.

I also agree with you that they should link to more specific articles in the tour page (e.g. How to Ask); there's a generic link to the help center, but it's not clear from that what items in the help center are important, exactly why you'd need "more details" to start using the site, or which details you'd need to know about.