# Expand the section on stuff not to ask about on the Tour page

Tags: feature-request, tour-page

Closely related: [Is the site tour actually particularly helpful in helping people formulate good questions and answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347969/is-the-site-tour-actually-particularly-helpful-in-helping-people-formulate-good)

Also somewhat related: [Rephrase items on the Tour page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339509/rephrase-items-on-the-tour-page)

Can we alter the section on what kinds of questions to avoid asking to read something like the following (proposed additions in **bold**)?

> Not all questions work well in our format. Avoid questions that are primarily opinion-based, or that are likely to generate discussion rather than answers.
>
> Don't ask about...
>
> - Questions you haven't tried to find an answer for (show <del>your work!</del> **what you've tried so far**)
> - **Product, service, software library, tool, or tutorial** recommendations or comparisons
> - Requests for lists of things, polls, opinions, discussions, etc.
> - **Questions about server or network administration**
> - **General tech-support questions about hardware and software that's not used primarily for programming**
> - Anything not directly related to writing computer programs
>
> **Questions should include [adequate details to debug the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).**
>
> **Please see the [On-Topic Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for more details about what topics you can ask about here.**

**Edit:** The [Software Engineering SE tour](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tour) has the following in their list of things not to ask about:

> ...finding or recommending products or services, including tools, libraries or packages, programming languages, books, scholarly papers, tutorials, articles, or blogs

I think that that's *much* clearer than what's on the Stack Overflow tour page. Tutorials, articles, and blogs aren't really products, so, strictly speaking, asking for recommendations for tutorials isn't asking for a product or service recommendation.

They also list "career or education advice" as an example of something not to ask about, which actually comes up fairly regularly - e.g. "which programming language should I learn next?" kind of questions. I guess you could argue that this already falls under the category of "primarily opinion-based" questions that the tour already warns against, but it could be helpful to be explicit about the point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I like the idea of changing **show your work!** with **what you've tried so far** because it's more accurate and straightforward.

However I don't believe that adding extra "micro" pointers will be useful because you're missing the point of a **tour** page - It should give the new user enough details on how to become a member in this community without getting "hit". We already have the help center for all the detailed rules of what is on-topic on SO and what type of questions users should avoid asking.

When reading your suggestion I immediately think to myself - "Hey, let's add a new suggestion that the user should avoid posting links to 3rd party websites and create a code snippet instead", then I realized that we'll probably end up with an endless list of good (or bad) tips.

I think that perhaps some changes *might* be welcome, judging by the amount of junk questions I saw only today, but I think that those changes should be based on statistics and real research for the common factors that are causing questions to get downvoted/closed. Needless to say that I don't have access to those statistics.

Comment: That's a reasonable point about expanding the tour page *too* much becoming a slippery slope. I think that if we make it too long there's also a risk of even fewer people reading it than already do. It does seem like *some* improvement is in order, though; e.g., I've seen people ask for library recommendations who had quite literally earned the Informed badge half an hour before posting their question. It's not completely their fault, either, because it's not clear from the tour that "don't ask for product or service recommendations" also means "don't ask for library recommendations, either."

Comment: @EJoshuaS I couldn't agree more, and I pointed out in my last edit that perhaps some changes are required. You're welcome to unaccept my answer if you want to keep this discussion alive and open to other suggestions/opinions

Comment: FWIW, "show your work" is a very common thing said by schoolteachers in at least the US, although admittedly it's often misunderstood there as well; the point is the same, though: it's not the *work*, but the *details of the person's understanding*, that are necessary for a good answer *that corrects misconceptions*.

Comment: @EJoshuaS Since you've edited and bumped your question to the homepage, feel free to unaccept my answer so perhaps it will attract new answers