# Reduce the number of votes required to close a question to 4

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, vote-to-close

Related (from 2009): [Now that there is a League of Super Heroes should the number of votes required to close/move be reduced?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11597/now-that-there-is-a-league-of-super-heroes-should-the-number-of-votes-required-t)

Also *very* related (but not identical): [Why are 5 close votes required?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261746/why-are-5-close-votes-required)

Lest this question be marked as a duplicate of either of the two previous questions, the difference between this one and the second one I linked to is that that post was asking why it was made 5 in the first place, I'm suggesting that it be changed from 5. The difference between this question and the first one I linked to is that the first post was written in 2009 and I think that the answers there are obsolete at this point.

One of the answers to the first post I linked to stated that "I haven't seen a significant number of 'bad' questions lingering for a long time." I assume that that was true at the time (I wasn't around, though, so I'm not sure), but as I write this the close queue has 10,000 items in it and a significant number of close votes simply age away, so even if this *was* true at the time, it's definitely not the case now. I think that this fact alone would tend to argue for lowering the number of votes required.

Another argument in favor of closing is the fact that the number of votes required to delete VLQ posts was recently reduced to 4, so why not make close votes 4 as well? If anything, it seems like there's an even stronger case for reducing the number of close votes to 4 than for reducing the VLQ queue since most of the time the VLQ queue's about 100 - 200 items long and the Close Queue has 10,000 items (plus the reputation requirements are much higher for close votes, so there are fewer people who even *can* vote to close questions).

A third reason to do this is the sheer volume of questions we get on this site. In the C# tag, a question that was written 17 minutes ago is already off the first page; this tends to hold across all of the popular tags. The high question volume makes it fairly difficult to draw attention to even well-formulated questions, which also makes it more difficult to get answers. The last statistics I saw had around 72% of questions getting answered, which actually isn't all that great. In fact, Area 51 states that a "healthy" public beta should have an answer rate of at least 90%; obviously SO isn't in public beta, but I think that the point holds - the entire point of asking questions is to get answers. Besides, that's how we typically get members - if we want new users to stick around and participate in the site, there should be a good chance of their questions getting high-quality answers. (In fact, I initially joined Stack Overflow because I was new to Android development and I was having trouble getting push notifications to work). Obviously, my point isn't to rant about that; I do think that closing lousy questions faster could help mitigate that, though (at least to some degree).

Comment: `Please do it.`

Comment: It seems to me that you're speaking from the perspective of one who navigates through the review queues.  I personally don't think such a reduction is warranted for the reasons provided, but I'd like to give you a chance.  Do you have any evidence other than anecdotal that would suggest that reducing the number of close (and reopen) votes would have a positive impact on the site?

Comment: Or at least make silver badged users casting votes to be counted as 2 votes, so the community can close questions faster (Because I believe that there is a place for improvement here)

Comment: I prefer 3. It is a nice odd number.

Comment: Screw it, let's close every question as soon as it's asked and wait for those that are worthy to get 5 reopen votes. That way we'll definitely get good content! :P

Comment: @Braiam I thought about that, but 2 votes will make such change less dramatic, while it also give more weight for users that already proved (By reputation) they know a thing or two about the topic they are casting votes on

Comment: Not sure if @clive is serious or not. Am going to go with serious. Upvoted.

Comment: I like @AlonEitan 's idea - we already give gold badge holders a dupehammer, so it doesn't seem all that strange that badge holding would include additional advantages for close voting.

Comment: I think this is too harsh of a tool to provide for all questions. It only takes 4 users to go through a tag and close 40 questions per day like this, if they feel it is "unsavory". I would prefer instead that, if it were to be implemented, the 4 close vote rule would only apply to questions which were negatively voted (as in, the question had a net vote less than 0).

Comment: @TravisJ I'm not sure that that would make all that much of a difference - the vast majority of closed questions have scores of 0 or less (except for some old questions that are now deemed off-topic because the rules changed since they were posted). If the question score is 0, you could bypass the restriction by downvoting it before voting to close.

Comment: @AlonEitan wrt silver badge holders, have you seen this: [Empowering tag-badge holders part II - let's look at silver?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240700/165773)

Comment: @EJoshuaS - Not really as concerned with 0 vote posts. If a single downvote makes them eligible, so be it. Questions which a user would vote to be closed are often also downvoted by that same user (although not always).

Comment: @gnat I have now, but what was written there _Extra weights' in current privileges - This is way too difficult to implement, and way too complicated to explain to someone new._ - What did they did it in the Documentation then? [AFAIK](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/331663/documentation-update-august-4th) _users with a silver or gold tag badge (from Q&A) will skip review when they make an edit to that tag's documentation_ - So it's possible, although difficult

Comment: @AlonEitan There is a difference between retrofitting a feature onto a new app, and doing so in an old app.  A really, really big difference.

Comment: @Yakk Well I hope they'll give it try, or change that constant of votes from 5 into 4

Comment: @TravisJ: As opposed to only taking 5 users to do the same thing as it is now? I mean, yeah, obviously, 4 instead of 5. That's it. Not sure what other point you're trying to make.

Comment: @NathanTuggy - "That's it" you state, but it is not that simple. In order to say that long standing questions will not be at risk from something like this, as it is a major change, you are burdened with showing **proof** of that "being it". Oh, just 5 to 4 for everything, no real change? Prove it.

Comment: Here is a good place to start with some actual data: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/286407/1026459

Comment: @TravisJ: My point is just that your statement sounds as though you're making a big rhetorical point, a really killer argument — "It only takes 4 users to [do something we really don't want!]" — but the argument doesn't have much force when considering that an awfully similar argument can be formulated for the current state. Maybe there are other problems that would result from switching close vote thresholds; I don't know. But that particular one seems rather silly to worry about.

Comment: @NathanTuggy - If something like this were to be used, it would be nice to throttle it to posts which were actually proven to be borderline, as opposed to posts which have been around for longer. For example, every question with 4 close votes (of which there are often a decent amount) would instantly be closed, and the bots would immediately focus on the posts with 3 votes (the low hanging fruit). This would mean a lot more closure for posts (perhaps valid in many cases), but it would be best to limit the target of that closure to posts which were at least borderline at first.

Comment: @TravisJ which bots?

Comment: 4 votes to close and 4 votes to reopen. Or 3 votes to close and 3 votes to reopen eventually. But we should definitely have this queue reduced faster for better visibility. Something was closed inappropriately? Reopen it and temp-ban the reviewers.

Comment: I like @AlonEitan's idea. At the moment silver badge holders don't really get any extra powers from having it, even though in some situations it can take years to attain it *(low traffic areas)*. If silver badge holder close votes counted as 2 that would really help close off poor questions quicker.

Comment: I'd love to see silver badges affect the strength of close votes, particularly for *too broad* and *unclear* reasons.

Comment: The original idea behind the dupehammer was to simply have weighted close votes. However, I think it was too difficult to actually implement. It seemed like either one binding vote, or nothing, were the options.

Comment: Then perhaps a *too broad/unclear* version of Mjolnir, maybe for people with silver badge and 20k rep?

Comment: I disagree with the score based throttling idea by @TravisJ. I find a lot of clearly off-topic posts (mostly tool rec questions) that are well written and have positive score, but should still be closed. (For the record, I find them because they attract new, link only answers or answers complaining that the links in the other answers are broken or the recommended tools are obsolete.)

Comment: It seems all people do these days the moment they see a question is glance over it to find some reason to obliterate it. I get it, there's an ocean of crap constantly deluging the site, and closing questions is low-effort compared to understanding a question and partaking in the race to answer it. But I'm perpetually distressed by the number of questions closed incorrectly. It's hard to fix that later because reopen votes decay over time and no-one's looking at the question any more. If you're going to reduce the number of close votes to 4, please also reduce the number of reopen votes to 3.

Comment: @Boann You really see that many questions closed incorrectly? I hardly see any.

Comment: The closing should be more dynamic. I agree that the review queue is too full and it's a shame that close votes erode away in time. On the other end of the spectrum, it takes only one close vote to close something as a duplicate under some circumstances, which feels like too much power sometimes. So a sliding scale would be better. Apply points to every close vote based on experience, rep, badges in the subject etc, then close when a certain number of points is reached.

Comment: Maybe 3 on consensus, 5 if not.

Comment: It always makes me wonder, to whom such earnest suggestions being addressed.

Comment: As Yakk said, it's probably too hard to implement something that grants different numbers of votes to tag badge holders. But if it weren't, I'd like to see the close vote threshold _raised_ to (say) 10, but with bronze badgers getting 2 votes, silver getting 3, and gold getting 4.

Comment: I get about 10% of my questions reopened. But most of them were closed incorrectly by gold badge owners.

Comment: @dalu I have 337 answers on Stack Overflow alone, so I apparently don't dislike questions all *that* much. With that said, I certainly dislike *bad* questions.

Comment: How about we close and delete the [thousands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3890183/webgl-framework/) of old questions, usually of the variety "please recommend a library" that [the](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43141380/data-visualization-could-anyone-suggest-me-a-lib-to-visualize-a-large-data-as-a) site is [littered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20016768/is-there-a-performant-json-based-db-with-a-client-side-implementation) with that stand as examples of valid questions to noobs since they have not been closed and have answers.

Comment: @gman it seems like it would make sense to throw them over to Software Recommendations SE maybe.

Comment: @gman tell Shog to make another run https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/341987/792066

Comment: I think it would be much more useful if Stack Overflow simply expanded the power of Mjolnir to cover the Too Broad / POB close reasons.

Comment: Given that even using 5 votes often there are cases of wrongly closed questions, I am not sure this is the best idea.

Comment: @giorgimoniava examples please? I would be happy even if 5% of the closed questions are wrongly closed, if that means that we doubled closed questions and close them faster.

Comment: I am not seeing stuck on 4 close votes that this would make any real difference.  This site has enough traffic that getting 5 is still a small number.

Comment: @Braiam No examples but they do happen.

Comment: @Paparazzi traffic != close votes! Only 160 users were using their close votes that hit the vote cap... the most active close voters are actually a slightly higher number out of [42k close voters](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/alltime/stackoverflow). Even if a 500 users were using in average 5 close votes daily, the would mean only 500 questions closed out of ~8.5k asked every day. Previous year, we got a little less than 1k questions closed per day, I assure you, that that number should be higher.

Comment: close queue size is somewhat misleading because it is artificially tweaked to make it look not-too-depressing for reviewers; actual amount of questions with close votes and flags is over 20,000 [as explained in much details here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/306180/839601)

Comment: getting just 2 close votes is often difficult.

Comment: @AlonEitan Could you post your idea (double-votes on silver users) as an answer, to be more visible by the community?

Comment: @Mistalis There is already an accepted answer and I wrote [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348560/reduce-the-number-of-votes-required-to-close-a-question-to-4#comment469612_348595): _"I don't believe this suggestion will be considered by the SO administrators/decision makers"_ so I don't see how my suggestion will help this feture request approved. Furthermore, you'll see that some of the above [comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348560/reduce-the-number-of-votes-required-to-close-a-question-to-4#comment469389_348560) suggest that it's difficult to implement

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Going from history, it seems that the real reason the number was increased was to prevent "closing wars," the same question being closed/reopened several times. It seems that such a solution wasn't actually enough until the "you only have one shot" feature was also introduced, after which the number wasn't modified.

> Allowing a single person with 3,000 rep to close a question isn’t really in the spirit of having a consensus that SO was founded on. It’s true that a peer can then come along and reopen the question at wiill any time, **but this then leads to ping-pong battles of opening and closing between two users.**
>   -- https://stackoverflow.blog/2008/12/31/i-move-to-close-this-question/

> Should the number of votes to close be reduced from its current number, or would we just get back into close wars?
>   -- [Now that there is a League of Super Heroes should the number of votes required to close/move be reduced?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11597/213575)

The "close war" problem was averted using other means, but:

- there's actually a stream of crap coming in,
- the median time of closing is [7 minutes, just too late for any answer streaming in](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/316682/792066),
- what [gets closed stays closed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266844/792066) unless you fix the question (aka edit),
- since reviewers tend to only vote on [the absolutely worst](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285534/792066) instead of the ideal "what doesn't reach superb quality" this would actually push the quality up,
- [there aren't enough users using their powers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285486/792066),
- the ones that do use their powers feel that is an uphill battle since they don't perceive the desired result ([fuzzed numbers were used to change this impression](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252572/792066)),
- whatever other problem I've forgotten.

Reducing the votes required would be like implementing "having more close votes" without actually shaving away the hopes on humanity on the already fatigued close voters.

Comment: "Reducing the votes required would be like implementing "having more close votes" without actually shaving away the hopes on humanity on the already fatigued close voters" Is this really a problem considering that prolific close voters already lost their hopes on humanity?

Answer (score -6):

[Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com) (then-Programmers) did an experiment a little while back, wherein the number of close votes required to close a question was reduced to 3 temporarily, to see if it had any noticeable effect. [Here's the meta post](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7723/146020) about it.

I'm going to draw attention to this section in particular:

> ### Why 3 votes?
>
> Initially users with enough reputation could unilaterally close and reopen questions on Stack Overflow. In December 31, 2008, the close vote system was created and required 3 votes. Between then and the next April, the limit was increased to 5. (Shog9 remembers 3 lasting a few weeks.) The documentation of the site setting reads:
>
> > KEEP THIS AN ODD NUMBER
>
> So we need an odd number greater than 1 and less than 5.

Assuming the same thing applies here, the only option for reducing the number of close votes required is to reduce it to 3. **I'm not comfortable with that.** Maybe not a *massive* number of questions are closed incorrectly at the moment, but even if it's a small number currently I think it's likely that we'd see a dramatic increase in incorrect closures with 3 close votes. It's significantly easier to get 3 people to agree on something than it is 5, even with a community as large as Stack Overflow.

Given that fact, I'd predict that the effect of this would be to reduce the size of the Close review queue, in exchange for *increasing* the size of the Reopen review queue. I'm not sure it's worth it.

Comment: _increasing the size of the Reopen review queue_ - Great! If people will **edit** their terrible closed questions and making them worthy to reopen then we did a good job by improving the quality of questions on SO, if not - leaving them closed is even better. Currently the junk out there is beyond belief

Comment: "increasing the size of the Reopen review queue" I would argue that the reviewers of the reopen queue are too lazy lately... or more like they are always looking for stuff to do.

Comment: @AlonEitan In theory, yes. In practice, I doubt it would make users any more likely to edit their questions.

Comment: @ArtOfCode I think you're right about that - And if they won't edit their question, then it will never be reopened. But currently there are over 9150 pending question for closer, reviewing some of them show that they are there for good reason - Personally I prefer a huge queue of potentially-edditied-and-now-good questions pending for reopen over the currently huge open and VLQ questions queue. And as a side note - I don't believe this suggestion will be considered by the SO administrators/decision makers. I HOPE i'm wrong though :)

Comment: It doesn't seem like inappropriate closing of questions is a major issue. I've seen plenty of questions that should've been closed stay open, but I've only seen a few cases of questions being closed improperly. Do you have some examples of that?

Comment: One of the problems with the reopen review queue is that's it sort-of broken @AlonEitan. A question gets pushed to the queue *once* on the first edit *only*. It doesn't matter *who* made that edit or how significant it is. I see questions pushed to the reopen queue just because someone made a minor useless edit (fix a typo, remove "thanks", etc.) far too often, which robs the OP from salvaging their question. It would be much better if edits by community members *wouldn't* push questions to the reopen queue, but only edits by the OP and explicit reopen votes would.

Comment: I also don't think those 9k questions in the close queue are really that big of a problem by the way. Many are old questions which should probably be closed, but *\*shrug\** if they're not. Given that SO has over 13 million questions, 9k is really a very low number.

Comment: *Why* does it supposedly need to be an odd number?

Comment: @AndrewMedico I see that you are the odd out.

Comment: @Raedwald Read the post again. "Maybe not a massive number...". More to the point, this discussion is old and dead.

Answer (score -28):

I do not like this idea. For a while now I've been of the opinion that SO is unwelcoming/unkind/unforgiving to new users posting questions. This attitude is demonstrated by downvotes and close votes without any explanation of how the new user colored outside the SO lines. I think reducing the number of votes to close will exacerbate the problem.  There's a lot of judging going on but not as much mentoring/guiding.

Note that by "new users" I'm referring to users asking their 1st or 2nd question. "Burn all the lousy questions!" isn't a great way to welcome new users to the community.  The question may be lousy but perhaps the person isn't lazy or stupid and did their best. I don't have data to support this but it's my impression that people are willing to take time to cast negative votes but fewer people are willing to take the time to educate.

Comment: What makes you think that only new users post bad questions?

Comment: I agree about it being unwelcoming and about the need for people to explain downvotes and close votes. I've always been of the opinion that it's counterproductive and rude to downvote or vote to close without explanation. Another big issue is that the help center is poorly organized (it's not clear what's important to read) and [the site tour isn't all *that* helpful to new users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347969/is-the-site-tour-actually-particularly-helpful-in-helping-people-formulate-good).

Comment: @Braiam I'm pretty sure he's not saying that. More of just the assumption that most new users post bad questions at first. Related, I suppose: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333867/meta-to-new-user-your-question-is-a-turd-that-cannot-be-polished-or-we-need-t?cb=1

Comment: That's not to say that we shouldn't close bad questions just because the OP is new, though, especially for blatantly bad questions (e.g. zero-effort homework dumps or things that the OP could've found in 30 seconds on Google); that's just rude on their part. I also don't think that lowering the number of close votes will make any difference regarding the issue of people being more welcoming to new users; bad questions will probably be downvoted into oblivion with snarky comments whether the number of close votes is 3, 4, or 5.

Comment: It's really not about us shunning new users to the site.  It's really about quality control.  The only real tool we have to educate the user are downvotes and close votes, since that gets the message across both faster and more concisely than simply asking them nicely.  Besides, asking nicely wouldn't scale on a site like this, anyhow.  It's really not intended to be mean.

Comment: That said, I also don't like this, but only because there's no hard evidence to prove that this will fix anything.

Comment: @EJoshuaS:  Yes.  We've already got a chatroom dedicated to closing off questions, and my brush-ins with them have demonstrated that this group and myself have a rather strong difference of opinion when it comes to closing and deleting questions.  I am genuinely concerned that this group or others like it can use their numbers to overwhelming close questions that they simply don't like, and with a reduced close vote on the questions, that will make this task that much simpler.  Conversely it'd make it simpler to reverse, but I'm genuinely uncomfortable with groups being able to close en masse.

Comment: @Braiam, I don't think only new users post bad questions; I'm sorry I gave you that impression.  I oppose reducing the number of votes to close because I have sympathy for new users.

Comment: Well, I don't have sympathy for crappy questions on the site. If you have sympathy for those questions, then we are in trouble.

Comment: What you describe is more of a problem with messaging. Closing a question is supposed to give the user enough information to correct the problem via the close reason used. Unfortunately, incorrect close reasons are often used as super downvotes where a downvote would have sufficed. In other cases the asker simply doesn't see the messaging or refuses to believe there could be something wrong with their question. Reducing the number of closevotes required doesn't fix either problem, it's instead fixing a different problem. I don't think it affects these two problems.

Comment: @Paul I have sympathy for them, too; I've made several proposals to improve things for them, in fact: see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347903/display-a-popup-when-a-low-reputation-user-tags-a-question-with-a-frequently-mis) and [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348368/proposed-new-language-for-the-tags-section-in-the-site-tour) for my proposals on helping new users tag questions as well as my proposal to reword the site tour section on questions [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348369/expand-the-section-on-stuff-not-to-ask-about-on-the-tour-page)

Comment: @Paul There's always the option to flag particularly snarky comments as rude/abusive (even if they're on bad posts that deserve to be closed) - I periodically do that, too. I actually think that that should be done more frequently - there's absolutely no need to be nasty about the fact that a question's bad, it's always struck me as uncalled for.

Comment: @Makoto, downvotes and close votes by themselves are not educational, or very marginally so. To me they're like a math teacher slapping a student when a mistake is made but not explaining what the mistake is.

Comment: @Paul I completely agree - downvotes are particularly uninformative, especially without comments explaining why. Downvoting without comment is basically saying "I think that this question is bad, but I'm not going to tell you why." At least the On Hold message gives some specific feedback as to what the problem is and gives some advice as to how to improve the question.

Comment: Maybe that's a messaging problem too. If you hover over the downvote button, there's a pretty clear tooltip specififying what could potentially be wrong with the post, but if you don't know where to look to get said tooltip... and you also have those who will simply disagree, and that's fine too. it's just a downvote. each user can only cast one vote, so if you get a bunch of downvotes... that's a pretty clear indicator that something is seriously wrong.

Comment: @Paul: "*downvotes and close votes by themselves are not educational, or very marginally so.*" Close votes are educational; the reason for the closure is right there. Downvotes are not *intended* to be educational. They're there to let *other people* know the quality of the question. It's a signpost saying, "stay away if you don't want to waste your time". The audience for downvotes isn't the asker; it's people seeing the question in a list.

Comment: I believe that a lot of the new users are introduced to SO when Googling some issues they are having with their code and the first thing they see is some 6+ year old question asking about a broad subject and getting wonderful answers. Today of course this type of questions is unacceptable but the new user is not aware to the fact that times have changed and asking questions this style will get them "burned" as you say. But I still think that we should be strict about the quality of questions here and not compromise when it come to new users. Asking on SO is a privilege not be taken for granted

Comment: @NicolBolas So based on the number of downvotes my answer has received, my answer is of low quality.  What I still don't know is why it's considered to be low quality.  Can you shed some light on this?

Comment: @AlonEitan Nowhere have I said or suggested that quality should be compromised. Downvotes and close votes are one way to improve the quality of questions but not the only way.

Comment: @Paul: "*So based on the number of downvotes my answer has received, my answer is of low quality.*" No, this is Meta. Based on the number of downvotes your suggestion received, people do not like it and/or do not want to see it enacted. Or they think that it's not well-founded. Whichever the case, it's a quick indication that many people feel that it's not worth reading.

Comment: Unwelcome is such an unwelcome word. The site should seem... daunting to new users, they should be triggered to make every effort to make their first contribution an exceptionally good one. If some people interpret that as "unwelcome", well. That's not very nice of them, to be honest. The implication hurts.