# Weave review queue items into ordinary question feed

Tags: feature-request, review-queues

The review queue is a somewhat daunting flood of work items that exists in its own, easily-ignorable space.  It is especially easy to ignore when you look at it and it says "9000 items".

I personally would be more likely to participate if the review queue items were just peppered in sporadically into the ordinary Q&A feed.  There should be some visual distinction to help show what kind of review state it's in and how many votes...so you could decide easily whether to scroll past, or click through to become involved.

If people didn't like seeing them they could opt out (similar to filtering out tags) and have to go visit the list manually.  Maybe you could even configure a slider of how many review items you want to have appear, as a % of your total feed.

---

**Quick description of what it might look like, in lieu of an image mockup:** it would be the same width and height as an ordinary question row, with the title and the tags being the same size and positions.  But clicking on it would not take you to the plain question view, rather to the view you would get in a review (e.g. a diff showing edits, with buttons to cast your vote).

It would have some different background color or border style...and instead of the area to the right of the tags having the name of who asked or last edited, it would have the review reason *(e.g. "This question was edited after it was closed. Should it be reopened?")*  The "Votes/Answers/Views" rectangle to the left of the question could be repurposed to say something like how many votes cast to reopen, or metrics more relevant to reviewing vs. to answering.

---

I think something like this would make it seem more like a bearable burden that everyone is passively involved in--instead of taking a user out of the ordinary Q&A process to a queue that many people (at least myself) find tedious to do one after the other after the other...

Comment: I like the motivation.  Can you sketch something out so we know what it'd look like?

Comment: I admit that if I was browsing and came across a review item in my feed, I'd look into it. I'm rarely in the mood to actually go into the queues and deal with stuff, but just having a single thing to deal with in a feed that I'm already in is easy enough to deal with; especially if I've exhausted all the interesting new questions. Which feed though? The main feed on the homepage? the `/questions` feed? And I think we should be able to have some control over participation and frequency of review items.

Comment: The last thing I want to look at is more noise on my feed. How is this different as a tool for deciding "whether to scroll past" than the vote total? I'll occasionally hit the review queues when I'm bored and *want to sift through the trash*, but I'm perfectly happy with that being in an "easily-ignorable space", because 9 times out of 10 I want to ignore it, and I want that to be easy.

Comment: @Comintern I feel the same way about some tags, and I hide them; I'm suggesting that for someone who wants to be idly involved in review, it would be a good way of kind of passively letting you do so without a headfirst dive into the trash bin... you should definitely be able to turn it off if it's not something you are interested in, but I would leave it on if it were not too much of a burden.

Comment: I definitely think there should be a Documentation style tag dashboard for tags. Like... if you took it straight from Documentation and plopped it right down on the main site... profit.

Comment: Wasn't this happening lately with community putting old questions into the feed?

Comment: @philipxy, Community bumps old posts that are unanswered, or have answers without up/downvotes. This isn't meant to close these questions perse, but to see if any of the answers are actually any good.

Comment: Something like this? https://image.ibb.co/gzW3dV/like-this.png

Comment: This should not be opt-out, it should be opt-in. And in that case, there's no real point in it when you can already just go to the queue if you want to review.

Comment: @TylerH I disagree, even opt-in it's still easier to review things on the startpage than to remember going to the review page.

Comment: `Please do this`

Comment: We also need to [reduce the number of close votes required to close questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348560/reduce-the-number-of-votes-required-to-close-a-question-to-4).

Comment: Look at the good side, at least is not over 9000.

Comment: plzno. the question list has enough garbage questions that need action.

Answer (score 6):

I agree with this, especially for the Close Vote queue. Given how perpetually-long the queue is, making it easier to participate in can only help the situation.

This is probably less necessary for the other queues like the Very Low Quality queue.